# C++ Error: String subscript out of range

Tags: c++, string, subscript

I wrote some code for my cryptography class and it runs on sagemath.com terminal but not in visual studio 2013. I'm not sure what's giving me the error though. I'm thinking it has to do with the `for` loops but I can't figure out what to change.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream plain1("plaintext1.txt");
    ifstream cipher("ciphertext1.bin");

    string line, cipherLine, key;

    if(plain1.is_open() && cipher.is_open())
    {
        getline(plain1, line);
        getline(cipher, cipherLine);

        for (unsigned int x = 0; x < line.length(); x++)
        {
            key[x] = line[x] ^ cipherLine[x];
        }
    }

    plain1.close();
    cipher.close();

    ifstream cipher2("ciphertext2.bin");
    ofstream plain2("plaintext2.txt");

    string line2, decrypt;

    if (cipher2.is_open())
    {
        getline(cipher2, line2);

        for (unsigned int y = 0; y < line.length(); y++)
        {
            decrypt[y] = key[y] ^ line2[y];
            plain2 << decrypt[y];
        }
    }

    cout << "File decrypted successfully." << endl;

    cipher2.close();
    plain2.close();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your debugger can tell you what line the error occurs. It means you accessed an element that doesn't exist.

Comment: Your second loop is going to `line.length()` but it is operating on `line2`.  If the two string are not the same length this may lead to problems.

Comment: @Neil Kirk The debugger just shows lines saying that it couldn't open PDB files. Not sure what those mean either.

Comment: @Matt They are the same length but I change it anyway just to be safe.

Comment: When you run in visual studio, I'm guessing that you are running in a debug mode which catches out of range exceptions. You will have the same bug on sagemath.com but it is just not reported.

Answer (score 1):

Your code assumes that lines in the plaintext and cipher files are the same length. Especially considering that the cipher is binary, not text (judging from its .bin extension), that's not a good assumption to make. If the cipher "line" is shorter than the plaintext line, you will get the error.

In addition, the key is always zero-length, so every single write to it is out-of-bounds. You need to either use `push_back` or resize the string first.

Comment: The plaintext and cipher are the same lengths though. I tried using `key.push_back( line[x] ^ cipherLine[x] );` but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Is there any reason why it would on sagemath but not on my computer?

Comment: @Andre Maybe `getline` doesn't do what you think?

Answer (score 0):

operator[] doesn't add to the string length.

```
key[x] =
```

will invoke undefined behaviour, which in this case is the out of range error. What you want is append or +=.

You are also assuming (which may or may not be reasonable) that the line and cipherLine will be the same length. You should be checking this anyway.

And your second loop is getting `line2`, but incrementing up to `line.length()`. It should be `line2.length()`

Comment: I changed it to `line2.length()`and tried `key.push_back( line[x] ^ cipherLine[x] );` but still get the same error.

Comment: @Andre, have you changed `decrypt[y] =` to use `push_back` as well?

Comment: Yup, but I still get the same thing.

Comment: @Andre, one of your other lines isn't the length that you expect. Attach a debugger and step through it verifying the length of all lines. Or print the length of each line that you read to the console.